# Node.js - get last subdirectory in directory by alphabetical search

Tags: node.js, unix, search, filesystems

Using Node.js, I am looking for a neat way of finding the most recent subdirectory in a directory where the subdirectory happens to be the last one if they are sorted alphabetically/numerically.

All the subdirectories are named by timestamp, like so:

```
- parent dir
--- 494985839399
--- 232111234483
--- 334433885832
--- 112221994948
... etc
```

Now I assume when you read a directory and iterate over its contents it's not guaranteed to be sorted by recency or alphabetically?

So, I am looking for a good way to find that subdir besides brute force O(n)  search. Unfortunately I will obviously not know the name of the dir, thus making a search or sort necessary.

What's the best way to do this with Node? It can be synchronous or async because this is not for a server.

Comment: brute force will work, but imagine if we had 10,000 or 100,000 files or something, I wonder if there is a more efficient way

Answer (score 2):

You can use readdir to get the directories in an array and then sort the array. Like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var result = fs.readdirSync('parentDir').sort().reverse();
var subdir = result[0];
```

This is not optimised at all (for example, you can make readdir async and make a custom sort function that sorts descending).

In one line:

```
var result = require('fs').readdirSync('parentDir').sort().reverse()[0];
```

(I did not test the code)

Comment: huh, that sort function is really on the result set that fs.readdirSync returns? didn't know that...well maybe sort is just on array.prototype...

Comment: `.sort()` is available from the Array prototype, which is the prototype of the returned array :)

Comment: Yes it is. `readdirSync()` returns an array and `sort()` works on arrays :)